# How would multiple mana doublers stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-manabase

If I have [zendikar resurgent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bzendikar%20resurgent%5d), [mirari's wake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bmirari%27s%5d%2b%5bwake%5d), and [mana reflection](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bmana%20reflection%5d) on the field, how would they stack?

Answer (score 2):

If you have all of those together and you tap a land for mana, Mana Reflection doubles the amount of mana produced by the land's ability, and then Zendikar Resurgent and Mirari's Wake each have an ability that produces 1 more mana, for a total of 4 mana with most simple lands.

Mana Reflection's ability says

> If you tap a permanent for mana, it produces twice as much of that mana instead.

This directly modifies the mana produced by the land's ability.

On the other hand, Zendikar Resurgent and Mirari's Wake both have abilities that say

> Whenever you tap a land for mana, add one mana of any type that land produced.

These are triggered abilities that triggers from activating and resolving the land's ability. These abilities produce mana separately from the land's ability, so they are not modified by Mana Reflection.

Comment: Mana reflection stacks multiplicatively with itself, though, so one land with two mana reflections produces 4 mana

Comment: There's also a comparison to be made to Anointed Procession (replacement effect) and Panharmonicon (triggered ability).

Comment: I'm not following that comparison. Those cards just do different things. Annointed Procession has a replacement effect that modifies token creation, and Panharmonicon has an effect (of unclear kind) that modifies triggered abilities triggering. The fact that Anointed Procession is multiplicative and Panharmonicon is additive is not the same kind of difference as in these question; that depends more on the technical details of the events each one is modifying.